# Parallel.ForEach questions

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am using a Parallel.ForEach loop in C# / VS2010 to do processing and I have a couple of questions.

First of all I have a process that needs to extract information from a remote webservice and then needs to build images (GDI) on the fly.

I have a class that encapsulates all of the functionality into a single object with two main methods Load() and CreateImage() with all the GDI management / WebRequests "blackboxed" inside this object.

I then create a GenericList that contains all the objects that need to be processed and I iterate through the list using the following code:

```
try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(MyLGenericList, ParallelOptions, (MyObject, loopState) =>
            {                                       

                    MyObject.DoLoad();
                    MyObject.CreateImage();
                    MyObject.Dispose();

                if (loopState.ShouldExitCurrentIteration || loopState.IsExceptional)
                    loopState.Stop();
            });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            // Cancel here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Now my questions are:

1. Given that there could be ten thousand items in the list to parse, is the above code the best way to approach this? Any other ideas more then welcome
2. I have an issue whereby when I start the process the objects are created / loaded and images created very fast but after around six hundred objects the process starts to crawl. It doesn eventually finish, is this normal?

Thanks in advance :)
Adam

Comment: What's the point of having a catch block that does nothing but throw the exception it caught?

Comment: Hi, this is just enough code to show what I am doing in may app, obviously no-one is interested in my error handling as it has nothing to do with the issue :)

Comment: Fair enough, but I would have left out the catch block entirely (the second one, obviously) -- especially since you're just sketching an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure that downloading data in parallel is a good idea since it will block a lot of threads. Split your task into a producer and a consumer instead. Then you can parallelize each of them separately.

Here is an example of a single producer and multiple consumers.
(If the consumers are faster than the producer you can just use a normal foreach instead of  parallel.ForEach)

```
var sources = BlockingCollection<SourceData>();
var producer = Task.Factory.CreateNew(
    () => {
        foreach (var item in MyGenericList) {
            var data = webservice.FetchData(item);
            sources.Add(data)
        }
        sources.CompleteAdding();
    }
)
Parallel.ForEach(sources.GetConsumingPartitioner(),
                 data => {
                     imageCreator.CreateImage(data);
                 });
```

(the GetConsumingPartitioner extension is part of the [ParallelExtensionsExtras](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx))

**Edit** A more complete example

```
var sources = BlockingCollection<SourceData>();

var producerOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 };
var consumerOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1 };

var producers = Task.Factory.CreateNew(
    () => {
        Parallel.ForEach(MyLGenericList, producerOptions, 
            myObject => {
                myObject.DoLoad()
                sources.Add(myObject)
            });
        sources.CompleteAdding();
    });
Parallel.ForEach(sources.GetConsumingPartitioner(), consumerOptions,
    myObject => {
        myObject.CreateImage();
        myObject.Dispose();
    });
```

With this code you can optimize the amount of parallel downloads while keeping the cpu busy with the image processing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. In the above example I would have to wait until each item had been retrieved from the webservice which may take a while. I was hoping to populate my object / create the image inside a seperate thread five at a time as it went though the list to speed things up.

Comment: No, the example have one thread that continuously retrieves items. As soon as one item is fetched the consumer part starts processing it (while the next item is fetched). If you think that fetching five items at the same time is faster just use several producers. (I will update the example)

Comment: Thanks again for your help; One issue I am having is with the  ParallelExtensionsExtras.dll, I have downloaded it, added a reference but the GetConsumingPartitioner never seems to appear. I get the GetConsumingEnumerable no problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, thanks; This seems to be the correct way to do it 
`code`Parallel.ForEach(BlockingCollectionExtensions.GetConsumingPartitioner<T>(sources), consumerOptions, myObject => {

Answer (score 1):

The `Parallel.ForEach` method with the default settings works best when the work that the loop body does is CPU bound.  If you are blocking or hand off the work to another party synchronously, the scheduler thinks that the CPU still isn't busy and keeps cramming more tasks, trying hard to use all the CPUs in the system.

In your case you need to just pick a reasonable number of overlapping downloads to occur in parallel and set that value in your `ForEach` options because you aren't going to saturate the CPUs with your loop.